# Generalization of Lagrange's theorem $(1768)$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, congruences

Here's the theorem :

> Let $p$ a prime number and $u_0,...,u_n$, a list of integers such that $p\not \mid u_n$. Then : $u_nx^n+...+u_1x+u_0 \equiv 0\pmod p$ admits at most $n$ solutions $\pmod p$.
>
> The proof can by done using induction on $n$ and the property of the prime number $p$.

Now, I was wondering how it will work if we consider an integer $k$ instead of $p$. The statement will give :

Let $k$ an integer and $u_0,...,u_n$, a list of integers such that $\gcd(k,u_n)=1$. Then how many solutions $\pmod k$ the equation : $u_nx^n+...+u_1x+u_0 \equiv 0\pmod k$ admits ?

I think we can start with the decomposition theorem $k=p_1^{a_1}...p_l^{a_l}$. Maybe it will give a system in CRT style.

Here's my attempt :

First important fact : if $k\mid u_n\Leftrightarrow p_1^{a_1}...p_l^{a_l}\mid u_n\Rightarrow \exists i\in \{1,...,l\}, \ p_i^{l_i}\mid u_n$.

> For a factor $p_i^{a_i}$ we try to find the number of solutions
>   $\pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ of the equation : $u_nx^n+...+u_1x+u_0\equiv 0
>  \pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$.
>
> By induction on $n$ I have :
>
> -For $n=0$ : the equation becomes : $u_1x\equiv -u_0 \pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$.
>
> The equation becomes $u_1x\equiv -u_0 \pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$. But we have
>   $\gcd(u_1,p_i)=1$ and by property of Bézout we can deduce that
>   $\gcd(u_1,p_i^{a_i})=1$. So $u_1$ has an inverse element and we can
>   take $x\equiv -u_1^{-1}u_0 \pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ which represents one
>   solution (the only one).
>
> -For $n=n+1$ : the equation becomes $u_{n+1}x^{n+1}+u_nx^n+...+u_1x+u_0\equiv 0 \pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$.If  I
>   consider $y$ a solution of the equation with the multiplicity $e=1$
>   (for instance) we have the fact that we can factorize the equation by
>   $(x-y)^{e}$ .
>
> It gives $(x-y)^{e}P(x)\equiv 0 \pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ with $P$ a degree
>   $n$ polynomial and with highest coefficient $u_{n+1}$ such that
>   $\gcd(p_i^{a_i},u_{n+1})=1$. So the equation admits at most $n+1$
>   solutions $\pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$.
>
> So there is at most $n$ solutions for $\pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ and for each
>   $i\in \{1,...,l\}$.
>
> If I want to use the CRT it gives a systeme of $l$ lines where each
>   polynomials admit at most $n$ solutions. How can I conclude $\pmod k$
>   (it's not a field) ?
>
> If we suppose that for each $p_i^{a_i}$ there are at most $n$
>   solutions we can factorize the $l$
>   lines with $n$ factors.

Unfortunately this fact is false (look at $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)\equiv 0 \pmod{9}$ which have $4$ solutions instead of $3$).

Here is the main system :

$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
           u_{n}(x-x_{1_1})(x-x_{1_2})...(x-x_{1_n}) &\equiv 0  \pmod{p_1^{a_1}} \\
              &\vdots \\
           u_{n}(x-x_{i_1})(x-x_{i_2})...(x-x_{i_n}) &\equiv 0  \pmod{p_i^{a_i}} \\
              &\vdots \\
           u_{n}(x-x_{l_1})(x-x_{l_2})...(x-x_{l_n}) &\equiv 0  \pmod{p_l^{a_l}} \\
           \end{array}
            \right.$

And for instance by Euclid's lemma (for the case of $(a_i)_{i\{1,...,l\}}=1$) to count the number of systems :  for $u_{n}(x-x_{1_1})$ we have $(n^{(l-1)})$ systems possible with one solution. It's the same for each $u_{n}(x-x_{i_j})$ with $j\in \{1,...,n\}, \ i=1$ right.If it's the case it will give $n^l$ solutions.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: start with two extremes: first, squarefree numbers $pq,$ then $pqr.$

Comment: @WillJagy later I will post an advancement. But we'll see where the problem is ;)

Answer (score 4):

By CRT, the number of solutions mod $k$ is the product of the numbers of solutions mod $p_i^{a_i}$.  So we reduce to working mod $p^a$.  But  you want to make your assumption $\gcd(k, a_n) =1$, not $k \not\mid a_n$.

Suppose your polynomial $f(x)$ has degree $n$.  Mod $p$ it may have up to 
$n$ linear factors, counted by multiplicity.  Each solution mod $p^{a}$ is also a solution mod $p$.  Hensel's lemma says if  $f(r) \equiv 0 \mod p$ and $f'(r) \not\equiv 0 \mod p$, there is a unique solution of $f(x)=0 \mod p^a$ such that $x \equiv r \mod p$.  But if $f'(r) \equiv 0 \mod p$ (i.e. $r$ is a multiple root mod $p$), there may be more: maybe as many as $p^{a-1}$.  So if $a > 1$ we get
a bound of $p^{a-1} n/2$ solutions mod $p^a$. This is probably not best possible, but it's a start.

Comment: Where does $\frac{n}{2}$ comme from ?

Comment: $f(x)$ has at most $n$ roots mod $p$, counted by multiplicity.  A root  that has multiplicity $m>1$ could correspond to $p^{a-1}$ roots mod $p^a$, while any with multiplicity $1$ just get one root mod $p^a$.  The worst case is that you have $n/2$ distinct roots, each of multiplicity $2$, resulting in $p^{a-1}n/2$ roots mod $p^a$.

Comment: For a root of multiplicity 2, why is p^(a-1) the upper bound (per double root)?  The number of solutions to x^2=0 mod p^a is about p^(a/2).

Comment: It seems that with this answer the maximum case is not reached when each equation $\pmod {p_i^{a_i}}$ has $n$ distinct solutions. I'm confused...

Comment: Maybe it is $p^{a/2}$:  that's $\le p^{a-1}$ if $a \ge 2$, so my bound stands.

Comment: OK.  The words "maybe as many as" $p^{a-1}$ in the answer seemed to say that $p^{a-1}$ was the maximum possible number of liftings of a multiple root mod $p$ to a solution mod $p^a$, which is only true when $n \geq a$. But actually $p^{a-1}$ refers to the number of liftings per element, and the argument is that (number of solutions mod $p^a$) $\leq$ (number of mod $p$ solutions)x($p^{a-1} = $ number of liftings of each solution to an element, not required to be a solution, mod $p^a$).   This could be made clearer in the answer.

Comment: @zyx I noticed that you can have more solutions $\pmod {p^a}$ than for $\pmod p$. Is it due to multiplicity ? That fact contradict my beginning of the proof ?

Comment: @zyx Could you be more precise about the "lifting" argument please ? Moreover notice that for $a<n$ the number of roots $\pmod{p^a}$ is the same as $\pmod p$.

Comment: Whether the number is the same depends on the Newton polygon of f(x).  This may require some correction of my answer, which uses only the multiplicity of the solution mod p.  I think that is correct when f(x) is monic mod p, as was assumed there, but I am not certain at the moment and have deleted the answer until I have time to check it.   @Maman

Comment: As for @RobertIsrael 's lifting argument I think it is as I wrote above: there are $p^{a-1}$ potential solutions mod $p^a$ per solution mod $p$, so the bound is (number of mod $p$ solutions) x ($p^{a-1}$) assuming that all solutions are multiple roots in the extremal cases.  I think the answer would be clearer if edited to say that.

Comment: @zyx maybe $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ ?